# Keep a sheet in first position in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a cover sheet and the remaining sheets are not visible.  A tick-box displays tabs if ticked.

The cover sheet gets moved around in the book.  I would like the cover sheet to always be in the first position.

Is there a way to do this?

```
Sub CheckBoxA1_Click()
    Sheets("A").Visible = Not Sheets("A").Visible
End Sub

Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    Sheets("B").Visible = Not Sheets("B").Visible
End Sub
```

The macro works well though the cover sheet extends up in different places well other sheets become visible.  I would like it to be always in the first position. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean the order of sheets gets messed up and you want the cover sheet to always be the first tab?

Comment: Yes - that's it Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Workbook.Open` event to move that particular sheet to the first position when the workbook is opened.

Add this code to the `ThisWorkbook` module and change `Sheet1` to the codename of that sheet:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet1.Move Before:=Me.Sheets(1)
End Sub
```